# Relative coordinates of an interior in a game

Tags: game-development

so I want to make a script for a game, which adds animations to interactive objects. The interiors are the same, but different position and rotation. I would like to calculate coordinates for the interior position, but so that it stays the same in all other interiors as well, no matter heading or coordinates. For example, I would like to have the "Take A Shower" interaction position calculated, and it to be the same in all interiors no matter what the interior's heading/rotation is.

I know i'll have to calculate the offset coordinates between player position and interior position, but I have no idea what to do with the heading. Any help will be appreciated.